# protocol buffers in android

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

I am developing an Android app in which I am using JSON, now for performance I have to test by using protocol buffers. If someone knows simple and easy implementation of this, please let me know.  I have been following [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-dataAndroid/index.html)  tutorial to implement it. The problem I am getting is in class generated by the protocol buffer compiler I have to no idea why I am getting error on importing

```
 com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry
 com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage
```

I have tried to add the protcol buffer jar from the "add jar from external resource " but it hasn't worked . Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the complete error message.